# format JSON response with \

Tags: ajax, json, coldfusion, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to format a json response as such:

```
[
{
    "id": "23029",
    "label": "F:\path\to\file\filename.txt",
    "value": "filename.txt"
},
{
    "id": "23030",
    "label": "F:\path\to\file\filename.txt",
    "value": "filename.txt"
},
{
    "id": "23031",
    "label": "F:\path\to\file\filename.txt",
    "value": "filename.txt"
}
```

]

but according to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), the \ is breaking the "structure"?  If I replace the \ with a | it works so I know the \ is the problem.  I'm using the response in [jQuery's Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default).

Should I be using SerializeJSON() instead?  If so, do I need to change something in the ajax autocomplete script?

```
$(function() {
    var cache = {},
        lastXhr;
    $( "#media" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
                response( cache[ term ] );
                return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.getJSON( "ajax/search.cfm", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                cache[ term ] = data;
                if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\` is the escape character and needs to be escaped itself if it is part of the content.

So, the `JSON` string should like this before the client receives it:

```
[
    {
        "id": "23029",
        "label": "F:\\path\\to\\file\\filename.txt",
        "value": "filename.txt"
    },
    {
        "id": "23030",
        "label": "F:\\path\\to\\file\\filename.txt",
        "value": "filename.txt"
    },
    {
        "id": "23031",
        "label": "F:\\path\\to\\file\\filename.txt",
        "value": "filename.txt"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 8):

have you tried to escape the backslash?

```
{
"id": "23030",
"label": "F:\\path\\to\\file\\filename.ext",
"value": "filename.txt"
}
```

Comment: I thought it was okay within the quotes.  I'll try to escape it.

Answer (score 4):

While other responders have pointed out that you should be escaping the backslashes, if you *were* to use serializeJSON() it would take care of that escaping for you.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what seriallizeJSON() would do to help in this case.